# Linux/Terminal Grep Total Memory

Tags: linux, terminal, ram

I want **only the number** of my total RAM size.

When I try `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo`, I get following:

```
MemTotal:        3943084 kB
```

But I want only the number, so i need to replace "MemTotal:" and "kB" with "" (nothing).
How to do this in terminal? (Maybe in one line?)

Comment: Typically `sed` is used for such stuff. It allows to filter input lines by a regular expression. See it's manual page: `man sed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be

`grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2;}'`

Which "splits" the input at whitespace and displays only the 2nd word.

Answer (score 0):

On more approach, with only awk use

```
awk '$1~/MemTotal:/ {print $2;}' /proc/meminfo
```